# 404 trying to use web api endpoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to add a web api controller to my MVC project. It's an MVC 3 project that I've upgraded to MVC4. I'm trying to get the "test" simple api controller to work, and currently getting a 404. Here's what I've done:

I've added all the required packages.
I've added my webapi config to my Global Application_Start():

```
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);  // Web API
```

This then calls my static Register method:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

I have a ApiController defined in my web app:

```
 public class SitechangesController : ApiController
    { 
        /// GET api/default1
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

And finally, when I build it all and browse to my site on localhost `http://localhost/api/Sitechanges` , I get a 404.

If I do a file/new project and create a web api project from scratch, I don't have these problems. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0):

It seems adding the web api config before the "normal" routes fixes it!

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); // Moved to the top
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller must end in `...Controller.cs`.

For example:

`Test.cs` and `TestControllerV2.cs` will return 404.
 `TestController.cs` and `TestV2Controller.cs` will return 200.

I see yours does, but I came across your post when searching for why a 404 was returned.